# ¿Cómo puedo guardar en mysql lo que recibo en un elemento id de HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

Tengo el siguiente script js que obtiene la fecha y hora del servidor

```
    <script>
        var dateAndTime = document.getElementById('dateAndTime');
        var hoy = new Date();
        var fecha = hoy.getDate() + '-' + ( hoy.getMonth() + 1 ) + '-' + hoy.getFullYear();
        var hora = hoy.getHours() + ':' + hoy.getMinutes() + ':' + hoy.getSeconds();
        var fechaYHora = fecha + ' ' + hora;
        dateAndTime.innerHTML = fechaYHora;
    </script>
```

Necesitó mandar la fecha y hora para guardarlo en una tabla mysql, actualmente lo estoy recibiendo en un párrafo por medio del ID, el cual es el siguiente:

```
<p id="dateAndTime" name="dateAndTime"></p>
```

Mi idea es mandar directamente lo que recibo en el ID del párrafo a guardar en mysql.

¿Podrían apoyarme para realizar esto?

Gracias

Comment: Cuando dices "mandar" te refieres a un formulario?  Si es así en lugar de ponerlo en el `innerHTML` de un `<p>` lo debes poner en el `value` de un `<input>` del formulario para que al procesar el formulario llegue a tu backend y lo registre adecuadamente.

Answer (score -1):

La solución que encontré fue la siguiente:

```
 <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {

        txtfechaN.addEventListener('change', function () {
                if(calcularEdad(this.value)<6){
                alert("La edad no puede ser menor a 6 años");
                document.getElementById("txtfechaN").value = "";
                }
        });
    });
 </script>
```

¡Muchas gracias!